# The apex of parabolic motion forms an ellipse of constant ellipticity.

Tags: geometry, mathematical-physics

I am not sure how well-known this is idea is, but here is a .gif illustrating it:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/THioGbt.gif]

Basically, the set of highest points of parabolic motion at constant initial velocity forms an ellipse, with eccentricity which is independent of both the initial velocity and gravitational acceleration. It's pretty easy to see that it's true, and I will work it out  here for completeness. The highest point of the ellipse (which will be the semi-minor axis $b$) is

$h=2b=\frac{v^2}{2g}$

where $v$ is the initial velocity and $g$ is the gravitational acceleration. The semi-major axis will be the largest horizontal distance any path makes before it peaks, the time of which we can find with kinematic equations assuming the y-velocity goes to zero

$v_y(t)=0=v\sin\theta -gt\rightarrow t=\frac{v}{g}\sin\theta$

Plug this into the kinematic equation for distance and minimize:

$x(t)=v\cos\theta t=\frac{v^2}{g}\sin\theta\cos\theta$

This maximum occurs for $\theta=\pi/4$, so $a=\frac{v^2}{2g}$ and the eccentricity is $e=\sqrt{3}/2$, and does not depend on the initial velocity or the gravitational acceleration.

Now, I think that's pretty amazing; at this point I've convinced myself there is no ellagant ("simple") way of seeing this fact, but I am interested if it might be a special case of something else.

For instance, my thought is that it is somehow related to the lengths of geodesics on a space of positive curvature, since we have curves from the origin of motion to critical points in a field of constant acceleration. Of course, it can't quite be that because the space actually seems to be more like a cylinder than a sphere, and I'm not sure what to do about the axes; I guess they would have to be measured with respect to a 3-space which my cylindrical surface is embedded.

Anyway; does anyone know anything about this problem, or if it represents a specific case of some more interesting geometrical result?

EDIT: Well, there has been very little interest in this question, and after ~5 years I am still fascinated by it. So what else can be said which might evoke some interest?

This is 2D kinematic motion, which means each of the two directions of motion are described by a polynomial. The specific polynomials here are

$$(x(t),y(t))=(v_{x0}t+x_0,-1/2gt^2+v_{y,0}t+y_0)$$

Of course, the answer did not depend on *any* of the parameters of this problem ($v_{x0},v_{y0},g,x_0,y_0$), but perhaps it depends on the order of the polynomials...at least, that's the only choice I'm left with.

So, perhaps each particular combination of polynomial order $(n,m)$ (where $(n,m)=(1,2)$ for this case) results in a different value of the eccentricity?

Does anyone know if it is possible to model ellipses with polynomials?

Comment: It's pretty well known that the optimal angle to throw a projectile to maximize its horizontal distance on landing is $45^\circ$, independent of initial velocity or gravitational acceleration. The horizontal displacement at the peak is half that.

Comment: Within the assumptions of the problem, the only possible things the eccentricity, semi-major axes etc. could depend on are $g$ and $v$.  A dimensional argument may convince you that the eccentricity cannot depend on either, while the length of semi-axes would depend on $v^2/g$. As also pointed out, there could be other similar dimensionless quantities, so this may not be really so profound.

Comment: The kinematic equations you are using are only particularly accurate rather close to the Earth's (or some other body's surface), since they assume that gravitational acceleration is essentially constant over the trajectory.  In fact, what appears to be a "parabolic" path for a relatively low-altitude ballistic projectile is just the portion of an elliptical path, with an eccentricity very close to 1, that lies above the planet's surface; the center of mass of the planet (assuming a small projectile) occupies one focus of that ellipse. A more general result calls for more physical analysis.

Comment: RecklessReckoner, I phrased the question in a basic way but I'm not so interested in exact $physical$ analysis. I'm thinking this situation can somehow be represented geometrically (a space of constant sectional curvature, maybe).

Comment: @ levitopher Graphics nice. Equally beautiful would be the  locus of descending circles of all $\theta$s  at various time intervals after $t=0$ .( Familiar fireworks display at night, that I recommend you to plot/post).  If you mark highest point on each circle it would perhaps give as bonus an insight into your projectile dynamics question.

Comment: The fact is beautiful all right, but there is not much of a question here. Yes, that's the way it is... so what? On a side note, did you know that the envelope of all those parabolas is _also a parabola_?

Comment: The fact that the envelope is a parabola is not overly surprising - what would be surprising (although maybe not in light of is already true), is if the parameters of the envelope *did not depend* on the parameters of the parabolas. This is what seems remarkable about the ellipse. I can't get a different ellipse by changing the initial conditions of this motion.

Comment: *"Does anyone know if it is possible to model ellipses with polynomials?"* For  $(x(t),y(t))$, with polynomial $x(t)$ and $y(t)$, to yield any conic, those polynomials can be at most degree $2$. If, specifically, $(x,y)=(a t^2 + b t + c, d t^2 + e t + f)$ then eliminating $t$ yields $d^2 x^2 - 2 a d x y + a^2 y^2 + \cdots = 0$; this is a (rotated) parabola, never an ellipse. *Rational* functions can yield the latter; eg, a circle is parameterized by $(2t/(1+t^2),(1-t^2)/(1+t^2))$. That said, it's not clear to me what kind of generalization to consider.

Comment: I'll note that I *have* considered the following: A family of constant-eccentricity conics through the origin, parameterized by $\theta$, where $\theta$ is the angle of the tangent line at the origin, and where the semi-latus-rectum of the conic is $p\cos^2\theta$ for some fixed $p$. (In the parabolic kinematic case, $p=1/g$.) The locus of a vertex is some not-particularly-remarkable degree-$6$ curve that happens to reduce to an ellipse when the family of conics has eccentricity $1$, so I don't find this a particularly-satisfying generalization.

Comment: @Blue: In regards to "what kind of generalization to consider", I think the direction your going in is a good one: "what orders of pairs of polynomials $(x(t,p),y(t,q))$ in $t$ will result in conic sections?" I guess eliminating $t$ will give you something like $f(x,y^(1/q))=0$ in order $p$....and then we are in algebraic geometry which I don't understand. But maybe still interesting!

Comment: @Blue: As for your second comment, I would be interested to know how the parametrization in $\theta$ relates to the polynomials in my original conception of the problem (since it appears to, if $p=1/g$ is a special case). Given the lack of concrete ideas, this sounds like an answer to me if you feel like spending the time to write it out.

Comment: Nice fireworks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a better generalization than in [my previous answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3283613/409), using a different interpretation of that answer's equation $(3)$:

> $$\left(\;y - \tfrac12\sin^2\theta\;\right) = -\frac{1}{2p\cos^2\theta}\left(\;x-\tfrac12\sin 2\theta\;\right)^2 \tag{1}$$

This time around, instead of interpreting $p\cos^2\theta$ as the semi-latus-rectum, we recognize it as twice the vertex-to-focus distance. This places the focus at
$$(\hat{x},\hat{y}) = \left(\;\tfrac12 p\sin 2\theta, \tfrac12 p\sin^2\theta - \tfrac12p\cos^2\theta\;\right) = \left(\;\tfrac12 p\sin 2\theta,-\tfrac12p\cos 2\theta\;\right) \tag{2}$$
which is on a circle of radius $r := \tfrac12p$. Let's use *that* as an alternative "third condition" from before; since the distance from center to focus is $ae$, we can replace the earlier equation $(6a)$ with

$$h^2 + ( k + ae )^2 = r^2 \tag{3}$$

Solving the new system for $a$, $h$, $k$ gives (upon discarding a couple of extraneous cases)
$$
a = \frac{\sigma r m (m + e \cos\theta)}{1 - e^2} \qquad 
h = \sigma r \sin\theta (m + e \cos\theta) \qquad
k = - \frac{\sigma r \cos\theta (m + e \cos\theta)}{1 - e^2} \tag{4}$$
where $m := \sqrt{1-e^2\sin^2\theta}$ and $\sigma:=\pm 1$, so that the generalized conic has this equation:
$$x^2 + y^2 (1- e^2) + 2 \sigma r ( x \sin\theta - y \cos\theta ) \left( m + e \cos\theta \right) = 0 \tag{5}$$
The foci have coordinates
$$(\hat{x}, \hat{y}) = (h, k + \sigma_1 a) = \left(\; \sigma r\sin\theta(m+e\cos\theta), \;\frac{\sigma r (m + e \cos\theta) (\cos\theta -\sigma_1 m)}{1 - e^2}\;\right) \tag{6}$$
that satisfy

$$x^2 + y^2( 1 + \sigma_1 e)^2 + 2 \sigma \sigma_1 y r ( 1 + \sigma_1 e )  = 0 \tag{7}$$
That is,

> $$\frac{x^2}{r^2} + \frac{(1 + \sigma_1 e)^2}{r^2} \left(y + \frac{\sigma\sigma_1 r}{1 + \sigma_1 e}\right)^2 = 1 \tag{8}$$

which indicates that *each vertex* of our conic has an elliptical locus. For $\sigma=1$, the horizontal axis is major; for $\sigma = -1$, that axis is minor. The corresponding eccentricities are

> $$\sigma_1 = 1 \;:\;\frac{\sqrt{e(2+e)}}{1+e} \qquad \sigma_1 = -1\;:\; \sqrt{e(2-e)} \tag{9}$$

that, as with OP's original scenario, are independent of $r$ (or $p$, or $v$ and $g$). For $e=1$, these are $\sqrt{3}/4$ and $1$; the first confirms OP's observation, while the second is extraneous here.) $\square$

Here are some animated illustrations, showing scenarios for families of conics with eccentricity $0$, $0.5$, $0.999$, and $1.5$. (In the last case, observe that no drawing occurs while $1-e^2\sin^2\theta$ is negative.)

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here's a way to generalize the geometry of the situation to non-parabola conics; unfortunately, the locus of vertices is not itself a conic (except in the parabolic case).

---

First, I'll reiterate OP's setup this way:

> Consider the path of a projectile, subject to gravity ($g$), that leaves the origin with a speed $v$ at an angle $\theta$ with the horizontal. Parameterized by time ($t$) the path is given by
>   $$(x,y) = \left( v t \cos\theta, -\tfrac12 gt^2 + vt \sin\theta\right) \tag{1}$$

Eliminating $t$, we find that the projectile's parabolic path has this Cartesian equation
$$2 y v^2 \cos^2\theta = - g x^2 + 2 x v^2 \cos\theta \sin\theta \tag{2}$$

or, in standard form, where I'll take the opportunity to define $p := v^2/g$:

> $$\left( y - \tfrac{1}{2}p\sin^2\theta \right) = - \frac{1}{2p\cos^2\theta} \left( x - \tfrac12 p \sin2\theta\right)^2 \tag{3}$$

Noting that $\sin^2\theta = \tfrac12(1-\cos2\theta)$, we see that the projectile's vertex, $(\overline{x},\overline{y})$, satisfies
$$\left( \frac{2}{p} \overline{x} \right)^2 + \left(1 - \frac{4}{p} \overline{y}\right)^2 = \sin^22\theta + \cos^22\theta = 1 \quad\to\quad \frac{4}{p^2} \overline{x}^2 + \frac{16}{p^2}\left(\overline{y}-\tfrac14p\right)^2 = 1 \tag{4}$$
which describes an ellipse of eccentricity $e = \sqrt{3}/2$, *independent* of $p$ (and, thus, parameters $g$ and $v$). This reconfirms OP's observation.

---

To generalize, I'll ignore the physics and concentrate on the geometry. We can capture *most* of the original setup by considering a vertically-oriented conic that passes through the origin, whose tangent line there makes an angle $\theta$ with the $x$-axis. This is not enough information to determine the conic, and it also does not account for the fact that OP's parabolas get *narrower* as they get *steeper*; it's not entirely clear which additional assumption is appropriate to fill this gap. This approach looks to equation $(3)$, recalling that the reciprocal of the coefficient of the squared term is the *latus rectum* of the parabola; accordingly, we'll take our $\theta$-conic to have semi-latus-rectum $2\cos^2\theta$.

To apply these conditions, consider that the general equation of a vertically-oriented non-parabola conic with eccentricity $e$, major radius $a$, and center $(h,k)$ has equation
$$(x-h)^2 + (1-e^2) (y-k)^2 = a^2 (1-e^2) \tag{5}$$ 
Then, we have the following:
$$\begin{align}
h^2 + (1-e^2) k^2 &= \phantom{-}a^2 ( 1 - e^2 ) & \text{(contains origin)} \tag{6a} \\
h \cos\theta &= -k (1-e^2) \sin\theta &\text{(tangent angle $\theta$ at origin)} \tag{6b} \\
\pm a(1-e^2) &= \phantom{-}p \cos^2 \theta &\text{(semi-latus-rectum length $p\cos^2\theta$)} \tag{6c}
\end{align}$$
where the "$\pm$" in $(6c)$ is "$+$" for ellipses and "$-$" for hyperbolas. We can solve this system for $a$, $h$, $k$ to get
$$a = \pm \frac{p\cos^2\theta}{1 - e^2} \qquad h = \pm \frac{p \sin\theta \cos^2\theta}{
 \sqrt{1 - e^2 \sin^2\theta}} \qquad
k = \mp \frac{p \cos^3\theta}{(1-e^2)\sqrt{1 - e^2 \sin^2\theta}} \tag{7}$$
(A second solutions switches the signs on $h$ and $k$. This corresponds to an identical conic situated on the other side of the tangent line.) Substituting into $(5)$, we have
$$\left(\,x^2 + (1 - e^2) y^2\,\right) \sqrt{1 - e^2 \sin^2\theta} \;=\;\pm 
 2 p \cos^2\theta \left(\,x \sin\theta - y \cos\theta\,\right)\tag{8}$$
When $e=1$, taking "$\pm$" to be "$+$", this equation reduces to $(2)$, so we have successfully generalized OP's parabolas.

However, the vertices of the generalized conic have coordinates $(\overline{x}, \overline{y}) := (h, k\pm_1 a)$, where "$\pm_1$" is independent of "$\pm$". That is,
$$\overline{x} = \pm \frac{p \sin\theta \cos^2\theta}{
 \sqrt{1 - e^2 \sin^2\theta}} \qquad \overline{y} = \pm \frac{p \cos^2\theta \left(-\cos\theta \pm_1 \sqrt{1 - e^2 \sin^2\theta}\right)}{(1 - e^2)\sqrt{1 - e^2 \sin^2\theta}} \tag{9}$$
Eliminating the parameter $\theta$ yields

> $$2 p y \left(x^2 - y^2(1-e^2)\right)^2 \pm\left(x^2 + y^2 (1-e^2)\right) \left(x^2 + y^2 (1-e)^2\right) \left(x^2 + y^2 (1+e)^2\right) = 0 \tag{10}$$

which, in general, does not itself describe a conic. (For $e=0$, this reduces to ellipse equation $(4)$, with an extra factor of $x^4$.)

---

Note that, since the parabola's eccentricity is $1$, it *could* be hiding just-about anywhere in a formula, waiting to be generalized.

As a specific example, motivated by a quantity appearing often in the above analysis, we could consider the "third" condition to be that the semi-latus rectum is not $p \cos^2\theta$, but rather $p (1 - e^2\sin^2\theta)$. The resulting vertex locus here is also generally not a conic:

> $$\left(\;x^2 - (\pm 1)(\pm_1 1)\,2 p y + 4 y^2\;\right) \left(\;x^2 + y^2(1- e^2)\right) = y^2 (1 - e^2) \left(3 x^2 + 3 y^2 + e^2 y^2\right) \tag{11}$$

---

It's possible ---even likely--- that some other generalization gives a more-satisfying result. Indeed, one could work backwards, replacing the latus-rectum condition with an assumption that the vertex locus is some conic (or whatever curve might be desired). Such exploration is left to the reader.

Answer (score 0):

Here's yet-another pass at the problem, drawing an even-more-general conclusion:

> $$\text{There are many ellipses!}$$

I'm posting separately because I'll be using a different parameterization to help streamline things.

---

The jumping-off point is the observation made in [this previous answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3283872/409) that the focus-locus for the variable parabola in OP's scenario is a circle. So, for a vertically-oriented conic, define a generic "upper" focus, $F$ as
$$F = r (-\sin\theta, \cos\theta) \tag{1}$$
(This $\theta$ is different from the one in my other answers. Also, $\theta=0$ corresponds to the top of the circle.) For an ellipse/hyperbola with eccentricity $e$ and major/transverse radius $a$, the focus-to-focus distance is $2ae$, so the other focus is $G=F - 2a e(0,1)$. For the ellipse (or the *lower* branch of the hyperbola) to contain the origin, we have

$$|OF| \pm |OG| = 2a \quad\to\quad 4 a^2 e^2 + r^2 - 4 a e r \cos\theta = ( 2 a - r )^2 \quad\to\quad a = r\,\frac{1 - e \cos\theta}{1 - e^2} \tag{2}$$
The resulting conic, then, has this equation:
$$x^2 + y^2\left(1-e^2\right) + 2 x r \sin\theta + 2 y r ( e - \cos\theta )  = 0 \tag{3}$$
(where $e=1$ is allowed). Noting that the semi-latus-recum is $1-e\cos\theta$, we can parameterize this conic with the help of the focus-at-origin polar form to get
$$( x, y ) =  F + r\;\frac{1-e\cos\theta}{1+e\cos\phi}\;\left( -\sin\phi, \cos\phi \right) \tag{4}$$
For a given $\phi$ the parameterization matches "similar" points across the $\theta$-family of conics: $\phi=0$ gives all "upper" vertices; $\phi=\pi$, all "lower" vertices; $\phi=\pm\pi/2$, all endpoints of the latus rectum through $F$; etc. Eliminating $\theta$, we find that the locus of each collection "similar" points is a conic:

> $$x^2 + y^2 \left( 1 + e^2 - 2 e \cos\phi \right) - 2 x y e \sin\phi + 2 x r \sin\phi - 2 r y \left( e + \cos\phi \right)  = 0 \tag{5}$$

Since
$$ \left(- 2 e \sin \phi \right)^2 - 4 (1) \left(1+e^2-2 e\cos\phi\right) = -4 (1 + e \cos\phi )^2 < 0 \tag{6}$$
each conic is specifically an ellipse. The eccentricity, $\hat{e}$, is given by
$$\hat{e}^2 = \frac{4 e \sqrt{4 + 4 e\cos\phi + e^2}}{\left(e + \sqrt{4 + 4e \cos\phi + e^2} \right)^2} \tag{7}$$
In particular, we have
$$\begin{align}
\phi=0 &\;\to\; \hat{e}^2 = e\,\frac{2 + e}{(1 + e)^2}\\
\phi = \pi &\;\to\; \hat{e}^2 = 4 e \frac{|2 - e|}{\left(e + |2 - e|\right)^2} = \begin{cases}
e (2 - e) & e \leq 2 \\[4pt]
e \dfrac{e - 2}{(e-1)^2} & e > 2\end{cases} \\
\phi = \pm \tfrac12\pi &\;\to\; \hat{e}^2 = 4 e \frac{\sqrt{4 + e^2}}{\left(e + \sqrt{4 + e^2}\right)^2}
\end{align} \tag{8}$$

Here are a few animations, for $e=0$, $e=0.5$, $e=1$, $e=1.5$, showing the ellipses for the four multiple-of-a-right-angle values of $\phi$.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]